# Rails3 Partial Question

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, partial-views

I have an issue with routes when i use this partial

partial  search

```
<% form_tag search_path %>
    textfield
    submitbutton
<% end %>
```

Then inside of my main index, i call the

```
render 'partial'
```

then when i try to use the text field i get a routing problem but in my routes i have

```
match 'search' => 'dashboard#search'
```

... Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
<% form_tag '/search' %>
```

Comment: Is that a new thing in rails 3? or why did my route not work?

Comment: I think the syntax should be `match '/search', :to => 'dashboard#search'`.

Comment: Maybe the tag should have an equal sign since this issues is tagged rails 3:   <%= form_tag '/search' %>